# Windows Form -- behavior of buttons?

Tags: windows, forms, button

First time I've used the windows form so I'm not very familiar with the interface. But how do I set behaviors when I add buttons? For example, if I want to click "Button 1" and have it open up a new window to enter information in different fields, how is this done?

Thank you.

edit: Sorry, I forgot to include the language. It's in C#, and I'm using MS Visual Studios. I've never really programed in C#.

Another question that just popped up: could I do this Windows Form in other languages such as C++?

Comment: Hooking the click event. What language are you using. Win Forms or WPF. We need info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the comment above is key but, if your are using the UI designer on a windows form then under the properties tab on the side of visueal studios, you can view 'events'. from here double click the event you want, probably 'onclick'. This will create a method stub with the event handler automatically set up.

Look something like:

```
public void Button1_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e){
     // open the other window for input
     Form whateverForm = new Form();
     whateverForm.show();
}
```

Hope this helps. Sorry im not sure about any c++

[Edit]
tutorial  not great but take a look:
http://www.ehow.com/how_7241167_tutorial-microsoft-visual-studio.html

Comment: Yes, I am using the UI. I'm just experimenting with the windows Form right now. What I don't understand is when I go under Event, and click action, and the drop down bar doesn't have anything in it. Also are there any simple tutorials on this?

Comment: What version of visual studios are you using the events tab was an addition to the Service Pack 1 of Visual Studio 2008. Do you have this or a later version.